# User flair on searches are cut in half

Tags: bug, status-declined, search, user-interface

Search results are not displaying the SO User Flair properly.

[screenshot http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/8348/66688989.jpg](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/8348/66688989.jpg)

Only half of the actual flair is displayed for results with summaries of more than 3 lines.

It's even worse if the result has more than 4 or 5 lines (flair doesn't even show up). It isn't a functional issue. But it looks odd.

Comment: Reproduced with IE 7. Not reproducible with Firefox 3.5.3 or Opera 10.

Comment: IE6 is all okay on that front. Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Can't repro in IE8, though I do see it in IE7 compat mode. Probably wont-fix since it's cosmetic for the most part.